# Inference of Subtypes of Generic Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

I want to have a function which takes some object and returns its `x` attribute. The object needs to be restricted to a generic type `Type<X>` and I want the type of the return value to be the type of the attribute `x`.

To restrict the input to `Type<X>` I need to use `T extends Type<X>` but I must actually set the `X` to some type value like `T extends Type<string>` which won't work with `Type<number>` or to `T extends Type<any>` which discards the type information of the `x` attribute.

I was hoping to do something like `<T extends Type<any>>(o: T) => T.X` or `<T extends Type<???>>(o: T) => typeof o`.

Is there a way in TypeScript to do this? If so, how?

```js
// Suppose I have this generic interface
interface Type<X> {
  readonly x: X
}

// I create one version for foo...
const foo: Type<string> = {
  x: 'abc',
}

// ...and another one for bar
const bar: Type<number> = {
  x: 123,
}

// I want this function to restrict the type of `o` to `Type`
// and infer the type of `o.x` depending on the inferred type of `o`,
// but to restrict to `Type` I must hardcode its X to `any`, which
// makes `typeof o.x` to evaluate to `any` and the type of `o.x` is lost.
function getX<T extends Type<any>> (o: T): typeof o.x {
  return o.x
}

// These are correctly typed
const okFooX: string = getX(foo)
const okBarX: number = getX(bar)

// These should result in error but it is OK due to `Type<any>`
const errorFooX: boolean = getX(foo)
const errorBarX: boolean = getX(bar)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then:

```
function getX<T>(o: Type<T>): T {
    return o.x;
}
```

Then:

```
const errorFooX: boolean = getX(foo); // error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
const errorBarX: boolean = getX(bar); // error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Type%3CX%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20readonly%20x%3A%20X%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20create%20one%20version%20for%20foo...%0D%0Aconst%20foo%3A%20Type%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x%3A%20'abc'%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20...and%20another%20one%20for%20bar%0D%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20Type%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x%3A%20123%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20want%20this%20function%20to%20restrict%20the%20type%20of%20%60o%60%20to%20%60Type%60%0D%0A%2F%2F%20and%20infer%20the%20type%20of%20%60o.x%60%20depending%20on%20the%20inferred%20type%20of%20%60o%60%2C%0D%0A%2F%2F%20but%20to%20restrict%20to%20%60Type%60%20I%20must%20hardcode%20its%20X%20to%20%60any%60%2C%20which%0D%0A%2F%2F%20makes%20%60typeof%20o.x%60%20to%20evaluate%20to%20%60any%60%20and%20the%20type%20of%20%60o.x%60%20is%20lost.%0D%0Afunction%20getX%3CT%3E%20(o%3A%20Type%3CT%3E)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20o.x%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20These%20are%20correctly%20typed%0D%0Aconst%20okFooX%3A%20string%20%3D%20getX(foo)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20okBarX%3A%20number%20%3D%20getX(bar)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20These%20should%20result%20in%20error%20but%20it%20is%20OK%20due%20to%20%60Type%3Cany%3E%60%0D%0Aconst%20errorFooX%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20getX(foo)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20Type%20'string'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'boolean'%0D%0Aconst%20errorBarX%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20getX(bar)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%3A%20Type%20'number'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'boolean'))

Comment: Yeah, you understand correctly, it's exactly what i wanted to achieve, but this just didn't occur to me.